# Using @fluentui/react (not the "northstar") to build UI for teams tab?

Tags: fluent-ui, fluentui-react

How do I use classic "@fluentui/react" (**not** "@fluentui/react-norhtstar") to build an app for Microsoft Teams? I mean, basically I would like to have the "classic" FluentUI lib to use the theme settings from the teams.